# Why my scheduled jobs are not executed parallelly

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-transactions, spring-scheduled

I'm trying to figure out why my scheduled jobs are not executed parallelly. Maybe there is something wrong with my transaction management? Method `JobScheduledExecutionService.execute()` is `@Scheduled` with `fixedRate=250`, so it should be fired every 250ms no matter if previous job is finished. Due to logs it is not working as expected.

Logs: https://pastebin.com/M6FaXpeE

My code is below.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class JobExecutionService {

    private final TransactionalJobExecutionService transactionalJobExecutionService;

    @Autowired
    public JobExecutionService(TransactionalJobExecutionService transactionalJobExecutionService) {
        this.transactionalJobExecutionService = transactionalJobExecutionService;
    }

    public void execute() {
        TestJob job = transactionalJobExecutionService.getJob();
        executeJob(job);
        transactionalJobExecutionService.finishJob(job);
    }

    private void executeJob(TestJob testJob) {
        log.debug("Execution-0: {}", testJob.toString());
        Random random = new Random();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(3000) + 200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error("Error", e);
        }
        log.debug("Execution-1: {}", testJob.toString());
    }

}

@Service
@Slf4j
public class JobScheduledExecutionService {

    private final JobExecutionService jobExecutionService;

    @Autowired
    public JobScheduledExecutionService(JobExecutionService jobExecutionService) {
        this.jobExecutionService = jobExecutionService;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 250)
    public void execute() {
        log.trace("Job fired");
        jobExecutionService.execute();
    }

}

@Service
@Slf4j
@Transactional
public class TransactionalJobExecutionService {

    private final Environment environment;
    private final TestJobRepository testJobRepository;
    private final TestJobResultRepository testJobResultRepository;

    @Autowired
    public TransactionalJobExecutionService(Environment environment, TestJobRepository testJobRepository, TestJobResultRepository testJobResultRepository) {
        this.environment = environment;
        this.testJobRepository = testJobRepository;
        this.testJobResultRepository = testJobResultRepository;
    }

    public TestJob getJob() {
        TestJob testJob = testJobRepository.findFirstByStatusOrderByIdAsc(
                0
        );
        testJob.setStatus(1);
        testJobRepository.save(testJob);
        return testJob;
    }

    public void finishJob(TestJob testJob) {
        testJobResultRepository.save(
                new TestJobResult(
                        null,
                        testJob.getId(),
                        environment.getProperty("local.server.port")
                )
        );
    }

}

@Configuration
public class SchedulingConfigurerConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(32);
        taskScheduler.initialize();
        taskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is scheduler will fire only one event, which will be executed by one thread and then I don't see you are spawning multiple threads in your logic for parallel execution. That call of jobExecutionService.execute(); in execute() of JobScheduledExecutionService is in that one thread. So overall it ends up being sequential execution.

Seems you need to put multi-threaded [Callable-Future based] logic in JobExecutionService : execute() to pick job [transactionalJobExecutionService.getJob()] and call executeJob() inside it. hope this helps..